# Find the absolute Maximum and minimum values of the function $f(x,y) = x^2 – y^3$ on the triangle R = {(, ): 0 ≤  ≤ 2 , 0 ≤  ≤ 2 − }

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need some help starting the problem. I haven't been able to make any headway on this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Haven't you learned how **interior** extremal points are obtained by setting partial derivatives to $0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Without derivatives:

For $(x,y) \in R$ we have $0 \le x \le 2$ and $0 \le y \le 2$. Thus

$f(x,y)=x^2-y^3 \le x^2 \le 4$ and $f(x,y)=x^2-y^3 \ge -y^3 \ge -8.$

Since $(2,0), (0,2) \in R$ , $f(2,0)=4$ and $f(0,2)=-8$, it results that

$$\max f(R)=2$$

and

$$ \min f(R)=-8.$$